# How to cleverly create an anonymous type from an IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

I would like to use LINQ to solve the following problem, I have the following collection:

```
List<byte> byteList = new List<byte() { 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x3, 0x4, 0x02 };
```

The data in this example follows the following pattern:

byteList[0] = address (1, 2, 3, ... n)

byteList[1] = old state, which is basically representative of an enum

byteList[2] = new state, same as above

I am interfacing with an embedded device and this is how I can view changes in inputs.

In order to clean up code and make it easier for a maintenance programmer to follow my logic, I'd like to abstract away some of the nuts and bolts involved and extract each three-byte set of data into an anonymous type to be used within the function to perform some additional processing.  I've written a quick implementation, but I'm sure it can be greatly simplified.  I'm trying to clean up the code, not muddy the waters!  There has to be a simpler way to do the following:

```
List<byte> byteList = new List<byte>()
{
    0x01, 0x09, 0x01, 0x02, 0x08, 0x02, 0x03, 0x07, 0x03
};
var addresses = byteList
    .Where((b, i) => i % 3 == 0)
    .ToList();
var oldValues = byteList
    .Where((b, i) => i % 3 == 1)
    .ToList();
var newValues = byteList
    .Where((b, i) => i % 3 == 2)
    .ToList();

var completeObjects = addresses
    .Select((address, index) => new 
    { 
        Address = address,
        OldValue = oldValues[index],
        NewValue = newValues[index]
    })
    .ToList();
foreach (var anonType in completeObjects)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}\nOld Value: {1}\nNew Value: {2}\n",
        anonType.Address, anonType.OldValue, anonType.NewValue);
}
```

Comment: For non-negative i, `(i + 2) % 3 == 0` is equivalent to `i % 3 == 1`.

Comment: I'm not sure LINQ helps so much here. MoreLINQ includes the `Batch()` method which is a nice way of chunking an enumerable into sized buckets. Alternatively, a simple `for` loop would likely be pretty easy and clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Range` and a little math:

```
List<byte> byteList = new List<byte>()
{
    0x01, 0x09, 0x01, 0x02, 0x08, 0x02, 0x03, 0x07, 0x03
};
var completeObjects = Enumerable.Range(0, byteList.Count / 3).Select(index =>
    new
    {
        Address = byteList[index * 3],
        OldValue = byteList[index * 3 + 1],
        NewValue = byteList[index * 3 + 2],
    });
```

If the number of bytes is not a multiple of 3, the extra one or two bytes will be ignored.

Comment: This appears to be the cleanest way to use LINQ to solve my problem.  I know that LINQ may not be the best way to solve this problem, but the question did specify that LINQ be used.  This question was meant as a learning tool, my production code will likely use a variation of phoog's solution.

Answer (score 3):

For simplification, I'd create a record type and use a `for` loop:

```
class RecordType
{
    //constructor to set the properties omitted
    public byte Address { get; private set; }
    public byte OldValue { get; private set; }
    public byte NewValue { get; private set; }
}

IEnumerable<RecordType> Transform(List<byte> bytes)
{
    //validation that bytes.Count is divisible by 3 omitted

    for (int index = 0; index < bytes.Count; index += 3)
        yield return new RecordType(bytes[index], bytes[index + 1], bytes[index + 2]);
}
```

Alternatively, if you definitely need an anonymous type, you can do that without linq:

```
for (int index = 0; index < bytes.Count; index += 3)
{
    var anon = new { Address = bytes[index], OldValue = bytes[index + 1], NewValue = bytes[index + 3] };
    //... do something with anon
}
```

Linq is very useful, but it's awkward at this task, because the sequence items have a different meaning depending on their location in the sequence.

Comment: I concede this is the most pragmatic and easiest to maintain answer I've received.  A variation of your answer will likely be the route I choose for my production code, but since the question specified LINQ I need to be fair to those that kept the framing of my question in mind.  Thanks for a great answer.

Comment: @Nate fair enough; I somehow lost track of the phrase "I would like to use LINQ..." by the time I'd finished reading the question and begun formulating my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this qualifies as a clever solution, but I used the example to try to accomplish this without creating separate lists.

```
var completeObjects = byteList
    // This is required to access the index, and use integer
    // division (to ignore any reminders) to group them into
    // sets by three bytes in each.
    .Select((value, idx) => new { group = idx / 3, value })
    .GroupBy(x => x.group, x => x.value)

    // This is just to be able to access them using indices.
    .Select(x => x.ToArray())

    // This is a superfluous comment.
    .Select(x => new {
        Address = x[0],
        OldValue = x[1],
        NewValue = x[2]
    })

    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must use LINQ (not sure it's a good plan), then one option is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> EveryNth<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e, int start, int n)
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach(T t in e)
        {
            if((index - start) % n == 0)
            {
                yield return t;
            }
            ++index;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<byte> byteList = new List<byte>()
        {
            0x01, 0x09, 0x01, 0x02, 0x08, 0x02, 0x03, 0x07, 0x03
        };

        var completeObjects =
            byteList.EveryNth(0, 3).Zip
            (
                byteList.EveryNth(1, 3).Zip
                (
                    byteList.EveryNth(2, 3),
                    Tuple.Create
                ),
                (f,t) => new { Address = f, OldValue = t.Item1, NewValue = t.Item2 }
            );

        foreach (var anonType in completeObjects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}\nOld Value: {1}\nNew Value: {2}\n", anonType.Address, anonType.OldValue, anonType.NewValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var addresses = 
    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, byteList.Count / 3)
    let startIndex = i * 3
    select new
    {
        Address = byteList[startIndex],
        OldValue = byteList[startIndex + 1],
        NewValue = byteList[startIndex + 2]
    };
```

Note: I developed this independently of Michael Liu's answer, and while his is practically the same I'm going to leave this answer here because it looks prettier to me. :-)

Comment: This is an excellent, succinct answer, exactly the type I was looking for.  Unfortunately I do prefer the method syntax when using LINQ as opposed to the query syntax.  Maybe my experience with python is showing through but it feels more natural.  Thanks for giving me an alternative way to get the job done though!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt to do it with an extension method `ChunkToList` that splits up an `IEnumerable<T>` into chunks of `IList<T>`'s.

Usage:

```
        var compObjs = byteList.ChunkToList(3)
                               .Select(arr => new { 
                                       Address  = arr[0],
                                       OldValue = arr[1],
                                       NewValue = arr[2] 
                               });
```

Implementation:

```
static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> ChunkToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int size)
    {
        Debug.Assert(list.Count() % size == 0);

        int index = 0;
        while (index < list.Count())
        {
            yield return list.Skip(index).Take(size).ToList();
            index += size;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, `SplitIntoListsOf` would have been a better name wouldn't it:     `byteList.SplitIntoListsOf(3).Select`...

Comment: I really like the fact that your solution works for Enumerable<T> and is fairly clean.  Very interesting way to solve the problem, thanks for showing me yet another way to get the job done.